# Adding a RewriteRule for a PHP page with special handle requests

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my php page I have a hyperlink like:

```
<a href=" . 'delete_user_page.php?name=' .$user . ">Remove User</a>";
```

The delete_user_page.php via GET takes the name of the user and executes the script. I want a URL rewrite mechanism inorder to **hide the passed variable**. So I wrote:

**.htaaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On #Turn on the re-writing engine

RewriteRule    ^delete/?$    delete_user_page.php?name=$1    [NC,L]    # Handle requests for "Delete users page"
```

When loading this onto the server and refreshing the results nothing has changed/showed so I realized I am doing something wrong.

1. Where does htcaccess have to be located relative to delete_user_page.php?
2. Looking at "delete_user_page.php?name=$1", is $1 correct or should it be different?

If there is something else wrong in my script please tell me.

Comment: Not familar with apache. Not know what is `[NC,L]`. But if i would do this on my server, it should be `/delete_user_page.php?name=$1` (note the `/`).

Comment: Also note, you should linking to `<a href="/delete/' .$user . '">Remove User</a>";`

Comment: You can use POST instead of GET to hide userid from URL.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt if I add the / it won't make any difference. I'm assuming in *your* server configuration your .htcaccess file is located in the parent folder

Comment: If you don't send the username to the server, how is mod-rewrite supposed to know what to insert for the `name` parameter?

Comment: @JonLin Can you elaborate? Anyway the username will be set before being sent off

Comment: If you use the URL `/delete/` and send that to the server, all apache knows is you want `/delete/`. How do you expect mod_rewrite to know you mean to delete the user with the name "joe"? or any other name? If it's not in the URL, or a cookie, then you can't use mod_rewrite.

Comment: I'm not much of a web developer, but I've always been told its a very bad idea to do DB updates and deletes from `GET` request. Use `POST` instead.